# How to delete negative duplicates from an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

How can I effectively delete negative duplicates of positive integers from an array of positive and negative integers like this:
[1, 5, 10, 5, -5, -1, 9]
as a result, I want to have:
[1, 5, 10, 5, 9]
(-1 and -5 removed as they are negative duplicates of 1 and 5)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the easiest method I could find :

- select positive numbers
- calculate their opposite number
- remove them from the original array

---

```
array = [1, 5, 10, 5, -5, -1, 9]

p array - array.select{ |i| i > 0 }.map{ |i| -i }
# [1, 5, 10, 5, 9]
```

It uses [`Array#-`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D), which should be reasonably fast.

Comment: Cool! You can even shorten this as `map(:-@)` though I'm not sure how many people know the proper name of the negation method :)

Comment: That's what rubocop converted it to, but you're right, it might not be very readable. To be honest, I've never seen it or use it before. Do you know why `@` is used?

Comment: To distinguish the unary `-a` from the binary `a - b` operator, not sure though why an `@` symbol is used. Guess Matz just made something up. Same for `+@` and `~@` but not for `!` which always confuses me.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What's the point of `+@`? And what's `~@`? SO is great, I really learn a lot every day!

Comment: Actually, I stand corrected. Ruby accepts `def !@; end` and `def ~@; end` but their names will be just `!` and `~`. Tilde is a binary operator that flips all bits in a number, the so called 2's complement. You can use `-` and `+` to freeze and unfreeze strings.

Comment: `array - array.select(&0.method(:<)).map(&:-@)` :) /cc @akuhn

Comment: @mudasobwa hahaha! +1 for smiley-style coding!

Answer (score 5):

You can do this in `O(n)` with just two passes through the array by hashing the positive numbers then rejecting from the array negative values whose abs was hashed:

```ruby
def reject_neg_dups(arr)
  positives = Hash[arr.map {|x| (x>0) ? [x,1] : nil }.compact]
  arr.reject { |x| (x < 0) && positives[-x] }
end

reject_neg_dups([-1, 1, 2, -2]) # => [1, 2]
reject_neg_dups([-1, 1, -2]) # => [1, -2] since 2 does not appear
```

Note interestingly that [the `Array-` solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41839709/244128) are considerably faster than others listed so far:

```ruby
require 'benchmark'

def reject_neg_dups_hash(arr)
  positives = Hash[arr.map {|x| (x>0) ? [x,1] : nil }.compact]
  arr.reject { |x| (x < 0) && positives[-x] }
end

def reject_neg_dups_include(arr)
  arr.reject { |x| (x < 0) && arr.include?(x.abs) }
end

def reject_neg_dups_arrayminus(arr)
  arr - arr.select { |i| i > 0 }.map { |i| -i }
end

def reject_neg_dups_arrayminusewo(arr)
  arr - arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,b| b << -n if n > 0 }
end

arr = Array.new(1000) { rand(-100..100) }
N = 1000
Benchmark.bm(15) do |x|
  x.report('Array-')    { N.times { reject_neg_dups_arrayminus(arr.dup) } }
  x.report('Array-ewo') { N.times { reject_neg_dups_arrayminusewo(arr.dup) } }
  x.report('hash')      { N.times { reject_neg_dups_hash(arr.dup) } }
  x.report('include?')  { N.times { reject_neg_dups_include(arr.dup) } }
end
```

Example output:

```text
                      user     system      total        real
Array-            0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.187512)
Array-ewo         0.200000   0.000000   0.200000 (  0.194663)
hash              0.250000   0.010000   0.260000 (  0.253355)
include?          3.660000   0.000000   3.660000 (  3.666313)
```

Comment: `Array#-` creates a hash too, but does so internally in native code hence it is faster by a constant factor but likely has the same `O(n)` complexity.

Comment: @akuhn good point, builtins are almost always faster than interpreted code, even with possibly equivalent big-Oh performance.

Comment: Being a variant of `Array-`, I expected my solution would have similar performance. It's about 12% faster with your benchmark.

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark! `rand(100) * (rand < 0.5 ? 1 : -1)` is just `rand(-99..99)` BTW.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've added it to the benchmark above, thanks.

Comment: @maerics: No problem. I think that your `rand` variant is returning twice as many `0`s than `1`s, BTW.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily using Array#reject:

```
>> a = [1, 5, 10, 5, -5, -1, 9]
>> a.reject { |e| e < 0 && a.include?(e.abs) }
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9]
```

To clarify with another example, this will not remove negative values that do not have a corresponding positive value in the array:

```
>> b = [1, 5, 10, 5, -5, -1, 9, -15]
>> b.reject { |e| e < 0 && b.include?(e.abs) }
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9, -15]
```

You can define a method like so:

```
def reject_negative_duplicates(array)
  array.reject { |e| e < 0 && array.include?(e.abs) }
end

>> reject_negative_duplicates(a)
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9]
>> reject_negative_duplicates(b)
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9, -15]
```

Or extend (monkey patch) Array:

```
class Array
  def reject_negative_duplicates
    self.reject { |e| e < 0 && self.include?(e.abs) }
  end
end

>> a.reject_negative_duplicates
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9]
>> b.reject_negative_duplicates
=> [1, 5, 10, 5, 9, -15]
```

Comment: Very readable solution. It's O(n^2) so you could speed it up by putting the original array in a `Set` for the `include` look ups to be O(1).

Comment: `self.` is not needed in the definition of the `Array` method, but I know some people like to include it anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr = [1, 5, 10, 0, 5, -5, -1, 9, -4]

arr - arr.each_with_object([]) { |n,b| b << -n if n > 0 }
  #=> [1, 5, 10, 0, 5, 9, -4]
```

Comment: I see this is but a minor variant of @Eric's solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby you could use the uniq method: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq.

Otherwise, you'll want to check an answer like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array) which covers how to build a structure to iterate through an array.

Comment: How would you apply `uniq` to the example given in the question?

Comment: CJ, best provide a code example with your answer. It is best practice on Stakcoverflow to provide examples in addition to links to documentation.

Comment: duplicates for positive integers are allowed so this doesn't work.

Comment: Also : `[-3]` is converted to `[3]`